# Wrong words translation - Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, localisation, special-character

I am facing problem while translating text, I have two stores views, **English** and **French**. 
On French store view the text is translated with special characters.
ex:

```
Qty = QtÃ©
Recently added item(s) = Derniers articles ajoutÃ©s.
```

It need to display "`Qté`" and "`Derniers articles ajoutés`" respectively.
I have added all the translation words in:

```
app\design\frontend\THEME\default\locale\fr_FR\translate.csv
```

But no success.
I don't want to translate this with inline translation functionality.

Why is this happening any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**This is the** `utf-8` **encoding problem !**

You have wrong encoding either in your IDE, database or in documents translation files. Ensure that the encoding is **utf-8** in :

**IDE while editing:**  choose the utf-8 encoding

**Database:** -> app/etc/local.xml `<initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>`or `<charset>utf8</charset>`

Database should looks like:

```
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[db_user_name]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements> //<---
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
                <charset>utf8</charset> //<---
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

Comment: I changed my sublime text IDE to with UTF-8 encoding and saved my files again. but no use its still showing same characters. Is there any other settings related Magento db?

Comment: Look my updates please